# HTML5 audio scrubbing past buffered region works in chrome but not Firefox

Tags: firefox, rust, cross-browser, html5-audio

I'm implementing a web based music player, but I'm running into issues regarding scrubbing/skipping. I'm using an HTML5 audio element for playback, like this:

```html
<audio controls id="playback-element">
    <source src="/source/12">
</audio>
```

And audio playback works fine. However, if (in Firefox) I try to skip past the buffered region as shown by the light gray highlight, playback skips back to the latest buffered region, like this:

[image: firefox scrubbing failure]

However, the same element works fine in Chrome.

[image: chrome scrubbing success]

The backend serving the audio file is a custom server written using the [warp](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp) web framework. The creation of the HTTP response for serving audio files looks like this:

```rust
let response = http::Response::builder()
    .header(http::header::ACCEPT_RANGES, "bytes")
    .header(http::header::CONTENT_TYPE, "audio/flac")
    //.status(http::status::StatusCode::PARTIAL_CONTENT)
    .body(data);
```

The status line is commented out because I've been experimenting with different combinations of headers and status codes trying to get this to work. [This MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media) (ignoring the fact that it's talking about ogg while my data is flac) says that Gecko can seek to not-yet-loaded regions of audio as long as the server advertises the `Accept-Ranges: bytes` header and returns status code `206` for all byte range requests. However two issues arise from this. One, even when following these guidelines, scrubbing continues to fail in Firefox, and two, when returning status code `206` is enabled, then Chrome fails to play any audio at all.

Looking at the developer tools in Firefox, I see that only one request is made, and it doesn't complete until the audio has buffered to the end:

[image: firefox dev tools]

Chrome, on the other hand, does what I would expect and fires off multiple HTTP requests with different byte ranges as necessary when scrubbing past the already buffered region, as shown.

[image: chrome dev tools]

Notably, however, this only works when the web server responds with status code `200`, not `206`. If I had to guess at a reason for this, I would say that the first request should return `200`, and subsequent scrub/buffer requests should return `206`, but I'm not sure how I would distinguish such requests.

Anyway, I would really appreciate any pointers on how to get this working. I'm considering that maybe HTML5 `<audio>` isn't the proper route for this. As far as I can tell, popular music streaming services like Spotify re-implement this themselves anyway, so maybe there's a reason for that. Or it's very possible some backend logic I'm missing because I'm using a custom server and not nginx, in which case a possible solution might be to host static audio data on a separate nginx server. Those are just my thoughts, really hoping someone can help shed light on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try by sending the `audio/x-flac` content-type.
Also, a range request is usually answered with a `content-range` header, maybe that's why Firefox is not able to fetch.